# How to get lamda values while using lagrange method in python optimization

Tags: python, optimization, scipy-optimize

I solve an optimization problem with an inequality via the Lagrange method.

I got the x1 and x2 but I also want to get lamda1 and lamda2 values. Is this possible?

```
x1 = Symbol("x_")
x2 = Symbol('x_2')
Z = Symbol("Z")
lamd1 = Symbol("\\lambda_1")
lamd2 = Symbol("\\lambda_2")
eq1 = Eq(Z, (x1-4)**2 + (x2-4)**2 + 
         lamd1*(6 - 2*x1 - 3*x2) + lamd2*(-12 + 3*x1 + 2*x2))
display(eq1)

def f(x):
    return ((x[0] - 4)**2 + (x[1] - 4)**2)

cons = ({'type': 'ineq',
         'fun' : lambda x: np.array([2*x[0] + 3*x[1] - 6,
                                -3*x[0] - 2*x[1] +12])})

x0 = np.array([2,2,1])

res = minimize(f, x0, constraints=cons)
res
```

Comment: what framework are you using? I'm guessing `minimize` is from scipy.optimize, but what are `Symbol` and `Eq`?

Comment: I just wrote it as an expression just for the visual richness. Yes, it is from scipy.optimize.

Comment: It's important to tag your question properly.

Comment: I just added it since if you can copy the code and run it you can see the equation and the main is here that whether you know if I can get lamda values from an optimization problem using lagrange method in python .

Comment: @Tatanik501 please add your imports next time you write a question, the code snippet is not runnable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming I understand you correctly and you want to obtain the lagrangian multipliers for the constraints at the solution, you can use the [trust-constr](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.minimize-trustconstr.html) method:

```py
res = minimize(f, x0, constraints=cons, method="trust-constr")
# the lagrangian multipliers for all constraints
lagr = res.v
```